# Simple char encryption outputting extra chars

Tags: c, string, encryption, char

I am currently trying to simply encrypt a char string in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encrypt(char *str, int size);

int main(){
char input[8192];
int length;

printf("INPUT A PHRASE: ");
fgets(input, 8192, stdin);
length = strlen(input) -1;
printf("LENGTH: %d\n", length);
char result[length];
strcat(input, result);

encrypt(result, length);
printf("ENCRYPTION: %s\n", result); 
return 0;
}

void encrypt(char str[], int size){
int i;
for(i = 0; i < size ; i++){
    str[i] = 'X';               
    }
}
```

However when I go to execute the code the output adds random characters to the end like below

```
INPUT A PHRASE: fg
LENGTH: 2
ENCRYPTION: XXà;ÿ
```

I'm very confused as to why it is adding the extra chars at the end. If anyone could clarify as to why this issue continues to happen it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A string is a series of chars followed by '\0'. Where's your '\0'? Also, what's that `strcat` call meant to do?

Comment: Yeah, look again at the `strcat`.  The `result` array is uninitialized, so it contains garbage, and you're concatenating it onto `input`.

Answer (score 1):

you've got the variables reversed in strcat

char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)

from here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcat.htm

Comment: just out of curiosity, was this the only problem?